# Java, saving a tiff file, always empty?

Tags: java, graphics, tiff, javax.imageio

This code provides an empty tiff file, I do not understand why.
The Canvas in which g is shows the line.

```
private BufferedImage bImage;
Graphics2D g2d;
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    bImage = new BufferedImage(sX, sY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
    g2d = bImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawLine(a,b,c,d);
    g.drawLine(a,b,c,d);
    try { ImageIO.write(bImage, "tiff", saveFile);}...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a color before drawing:

```
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Thanks , No it did do it..

Answer (score 0):

I found that `ImageIO.write(bImage, "tiff", saveFile);` returns `false`.

Javadoc says:`Returns : false if no appropriate writer is found.`

Question: What means no appropriate writer found?

Comment: may have found an answer here :

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956941/imageio-write-bmp-does-not-work

Comment: works with bmp, not tif

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this problem.

> 1- install java SE8
>
> 2- load library jai_imageio-1.1.jar in build path